# Object Expression as Computation Builder

Tags: f#

Given a generic interface declaration like

```
type IFoo<'T,'MT> =
    abstract Return : 'T -> 'MT
    abstract Bind : 'MT * ('T -> 'MT) -> 'MT
```

it's actually possible to use object expressions as computation builder expressions, which could provide for an interesting approach to the division between encapsulation and execution logic of monadic workflows.

```
let inline addOption mx my = 
    {   new IFoo<_,_> with
        member __.Return x = Some x
        member __.Bind(ma, f) = Option.bind f ma }
        {   let! x = mx
            let! y = my
            return x + y }
// val inline addOption :
//   mx: ^a option -> my: ^a option ->  ^a option
//     when  ^a : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a)

addOption (Some 1) (Some 2)
// val it : int option = Some 3
addOption None (Some 2)
// val it : int option = None
```

The compiler checks on the type of the expression if the expected methods are present. But it is only halfway there; because for real monads, I would need to get the method signature `abstract Bind : 'MT * ('T -> 'MU) -> 'MU` honoured, a projection to a different non-encapsulated type. Why can't this be done?

Comment: For a real monad, you need `'MT` and `'T` to be related, too, which is not possible in the .NET type system.  As I understand it, you'd ideally want something more like `type IFoo<'M<_>> = abstract Return : 'T -> 'M<'T> ...` (so that `'T` is a generic parameter for the method, not the class), but you can't do this without higher-kinded types.

Comment: Did you look into free monads? Your question feels like that's where you want to arrive at...